# Get rid of [by-reference] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [by-reference](/questions/tagged/by-reference) tag is ambiguously used to denote either a popular notion of a reference to an object in OOP languages or some specific "things" in particular languages/frameworks (even though they're of course probably related to some general notion of a "reference").

There are currently [28 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/by-reference) with this tag, and it doesn't look necessary nor informative. Most of the time, the word "reference" has to be used in the title anyway, and in general it just seems too broad.

Comment: Nice catch. I've done some of them re-tagging them as [tag:pass-by-reference] [tag:reference] or other tags as appropriate or removed it completely when it was irrelevant.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Didn't know about the `pass-by-reference` tag. `by-reference` should probably be added as a synonym then.

Comment: ... or maybe not, as you can imagine returning something by reference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to quick reaction of some people (in particular, when retagging I've noticed also [ProgramFOX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619912/programfox) and [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum)) this tag is no longer used :-) Good job!